# Powershell - Multiple Sets of Parameter Sets

Tags: powershell, parameter-sets

Consider these parameters:

```
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string[]]$UserId,

        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string[]]$EmployeeId,

        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string[]]$GroupId,

        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string[]]$GroupName
```

- UserId & EmployeeId are mutually exclusive
- GroupId & GroupName are mutually exclusive

All of them are mandatory; read: At least one of, UserId or EmployeeId; At least one of, GroupId or GroupName.

Another way to look at it; A & B are mutually exclusive; C & D are mutually exclusive

---

- A - UserId
- B - EmployeeId
- C - GroupId
- D - GroupName

Possible Combinations I want:

- AC
- AD
- BC
- BD

I have tried to use multiple parameter sets to accomplish this but I am clearly not doing something correctly.  I can't seem to work out the correct combination of parameter sets.  I did see several example posts on this topic and tried to apply it to this use case; I was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of "possible combinations" is your list of parameter sets - now you just need to apply them to each relevant parameter:

```
function Test-ParamSet {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'UserIdGroupId')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'UserIdGroupName')]
        [string[]]$UserId,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'EmployeeIdGroupId')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'EmployeeIdGroupName')]
        [string[]]$EmployeeId,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'UserIdGroupId')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'EmployeeIdGroupId')]
        [string[]]$GroupId,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'UserIdGroupName')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'EmployeeIdGroupName')]
        [string[]]$GroupName
    )

    $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
}
```

Resulting in the following parameter set resolution behavior:

```
PS ~> Test-ParamSet -UserId abc -GroupId 123
UserIdGroupId
PS ~> Test-ParamSet -UserId abc -GroupName 123
UserIdGroupName
PS ~> Test-ParamSet -EmployeeId abc -GroupId 123
EmployeeIdGroupId
PS ~> Test-ParamSet -EmployeeId abc -GroupName 123
EmployeeIdGroupName
```

Comment: This visualization was perfect to help me understand where I was going wrong.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks